# Is this encapsulation?

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation

I read many times about encapsulation, but always I see a code like this I finish wondering the same. Is it this encapsulation?

```
class create_active_parent{



function __construct(){
     //something
}


function clean_queues_redis(){
    //creating in this way an object, and using it, is not encapsulation, is it?
    $redis = RedisDB::fetch_instance();        
    $redis->db->flushdb();  
}
```

Comment: No. [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming))

Comment: Yes, I understand what I read. But in this way $redis is hidden from outside......it's because of that I doubt

Comment: @itaka: `$redis` is a local variable in that function, however `RedisDB` is a super global classname and the global static function `RedisDB::fetch_instance()` returns the object you refer to with the local `$redis` variable *everywhere*. Using the shorter notation shows this better: `RedisDB::fetch_instance()->db->flushdb();` - As this shows, nothing is encapsulated because `Redis` offers nothing to support actual encapsulation. Pure global static state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encapsulation is to hide private **fields** from outside. `$redis` is just a **local variable**, and it will die at the end of `clean_queues_redis` method execution.

Comment: Actually the hiding of fields is called "information hiding" encapsulation is just a way of grouping data, and may or may not be used along with information hiding

Answer (score 0):

About Encapsulation:

Imagine an application that manages sensitive data from a group of People (e.g., some big Company or a Bank), we can write the following class to illustrate a how we could handle this information.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CarbonBasedLifeform joeBloggs = new CarbonBasedLifeform("Joe Bloggs", "987-65-4320");
        System.out.println(joeBloggs.name);
    }
}
class CarbonBasedLifeform {
    String name;
    String SSN;
    public CarbonBasedLifeform(String name, String SSN)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.SSN = SSN;     
    }
}
```

If you run this code you will create a class called “CarbonBasedLifeform” and also created an instance, Joe Bloggs, now imagine that some other programmer is adding more stuff to the program and they start messing around with some of this data, what if they change Joe’s Social Security Number? Or even his name? We don’t have anything to protect the access to the attributes of the class, so it can be easily done:

```
joeBloggs.SSN = "0987654321";
```

If people could just modify each other’s documents and alter personal data like that, what an odd, disturbing world that would be. Joe is the only one that can go through the bureaucratic loops to get new documents, this stuff is private, that’s why it is a common practice to add modifiers to the class attributes along with special methods to control the access to their values, i.e., the Getters & Setters:

```
class CarbonBasedLifeform {
    private String name;
    private String SSN;
    public CarbonBasedLifeform(String name, String SSN) {
        this.name = name;
        this.SSN = SSN;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSSN() {
        return this.SSN;
    }
    public void setSSN(String SSN) {
        if(verifyRedTape())
            this.SSN = SSN;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the other classes can’t change Joe’s attributes directly, because the attributes are marked as `private`  and the methods provide a mechanism to control how other classes interact with this data, that is known as Encapsulation or, in other words, **don’t touch Joe’s privates!**